# lambda node.js async function can't access to callbacks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, callback

I m using async function and i faced problem in accessing to the callback function.

I can console.log( req) successfully but not (res) neither  (body)

all the console.log inside the  callbackfunction are not displayed , I only get the (req) response

```
module.exports.handler = async function (event,context){

               let result = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
                console.log(result.Contents);

                var req = http.request(post_options,function(res) {
                    console.log("resresresresresres");
                   console.log("statusstatusstatustats");
                   console.log("headersheadersheaders");
                   res.setEncoding('utf8');
                   res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                       console.log("body");
                   });
                });
            console.log(req)
              
                }
```

I tried it this way also and im getting the same result , only the (req) is displayed

```
module.exports.handler = async function (event,context){

                    let result = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
                    console.log(result.Contents);

                var req = http.request(post_options,res=> {
                    console.log("resresresresresres");
                   console.log("statusstatusstatustats");
                   console.log("headersheadersheaders");
                   res.setEncoding('utf8');
                   res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                       console.log("body");
                   });
                });
            console.log(req)
              
                }
```

Comment: Your http.request() is likely encountering an error, andyou have no error handler.  Add something along the lines of `req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})`

Comment: Im not getting anything , the same as the previous console.logs

Comment: Add `req.on('error', e=>  console.log(e))` right above the `console.log(req)`and check out the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promisify the http.request call.

```
function postCall(postOptions) {
     http.request(postOptions, function(res) {
         console.log("resresresresresres");
         console.log("statusstatusstatustats");
         console.log("headersheadersheaders");
         res.setEncoding('utf8');
         res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            return chunk;
         });
     });
    }
    
or

function postCall(postOptions) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   http.request(postOptions, function(res) {
     console.log("resresresresresres");
     console.log("statusstatusstatustats");
     console.log("headersheadersheaders");
     res.setEncoding('utf8');
     res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        resolve(chunk);
     });
 });
 })
}

Then Lambda function

module.exports.handler = async function (event,context){
  let result = await s3.listObjects(params).promise();
  console.log(result.Contents);
  // please define post request params i.e postOptions
  const response = await postCall(postOptions);
  console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I tried it the first way and it woerked.Tahnk you.